# Is there any way to do exact match in case of TEXT field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am passing match query as "a b c" with "operator":"and" but also, getting "a b c d" in the resultSet (as Expected). Is there any way to eliminate "a b c d"?

Comment: Can you show your index mapping?

Comment: Can you post the mapping and query?

Answer (score 0):

### Mapping

```
{
"settings":{

},
"mappings":{
    "test3_type": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields":{
                    "word_count":{
                        "type":"token_count",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

### Indexing records

```
{"index": {}} {"text": ["a b c d", "a b c x", "b a c y"]}{"index": {}}{"text": ["a b c"]}
```

### Query records

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "text": {
                        "query": "b c a"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "text.word_count": "3"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to eliminate `d` from your search, this can be easily done by adding a `must_not` leaf to your `compound-query`.

```
{
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "a b c",
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "must_not": {
                    "match": {
                        "content": "d"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

`constant-score` improves performance by caching the results by executing the query in a `non-scoring` aka `filter` context. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Results:

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 2,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            ...
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "a b c"
            }
        },
        {   ...
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "content": "a b c f"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do an exact match you can use "match_phrase" instead of "match" in your query and to eliminate the "a b c d" type string you can simply place it inside a "must_not" block.      example:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "field": "value"
        }
      }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```